# Method findTopBy (JPA) returns differents objects

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, findby

I am new to Java and I have a question:

I have a method in *MessageRepo*:

```
Message findTopByOwnerOrderById(User user);
```

And every time it returns a different Message, although it should only return the **first** from **sorted** data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

look at this link show all hibernate method in spring boot
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

and i want show more details like Message Class